# Detecting if facebook app is installed on idevice

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I Want to add a function to my game so that the user can share his highscore with his friends on facebook.

Now to do that, I first want to know if the facebook app is installed on his device, if not, he wil not see the function to share his highscore on facebook.

I AM using swift so I added the facebookSDK with a bridge-header.h file.

This is the code given by an example of facebook:

```
FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/book/Snow-Crash.html"];
BOOL canShare = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params];
if (canShare) {
 // FBDialogs call to open Share dialog
}
```

Now this is in Objective-C, I tried to convert this to Swift and now this is my code:

```
    let params = FBShareDialogParams()
    params.link = NSURL(URLWithString:"https://example.com/book/Snow-Crash.html")
    let canShare:Bool = (FBDialogs.canPresentShareDialogWithParams(params))
    if (canShare) {
        // FBDialogs call to open Share dialog
    }
```

But now I get the error: FBShareDialogParams is unavailable

Bridge header looks like:

```
#ifndef FrogCross2_Bridge_Header_h
#define FrogCross2_Bridge_Header_h


#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

#endif
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the bridge-header look like?

Comment: The inevitable missing-the-point comment: you can share on Facebook using the Social Framework alone, which is available everywhere Swift is. You also might consider a `UIActivityViewController` rather than writing stuff yourself; it'll allow them to share on Facebook, Twitter, Sina Weibo, whatever else iOS ends up supporting. So possibly greater exposure for your product, without any extra work. It's "a standard view controller that you can use to offer various services from your application. The system provides several standard services, such as ... posting content to social media sites"

Comment: Can you direct me to an tutorial or example or sample code? beacause I am working on it for 3 days now and can not find anything useful..

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a work around, there may be a better way to do it, but you can make an attempt to open a Facebook url using the Facebook url scheme like so:

```
func facebookInstalled() -> Bool {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb://")!) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I tried this on the simulator and it evaluated at false, but when I tried it on my device, it evaluated as true.